# Android Ez vCard library - writing multiple vCards

Tags: java, android, vcf-vcard

I am trying to use the Android [ez vcard library](https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard-android) to create vcf file from my object. My problem is I have no idea how to instantiate a `List` of VCards, like so:

```
List<VCard> vcards = null ;
```

I tried:

```
List<VCard> vcards = new List<VCard>();
```

but then it insists on implementing methods to look like this:

```
 List<VCard> vcards = new List<VCard>() {
                        @Override
                        public void add(int location, VCard object) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean add(VCard object) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean addAll(int location, Collection<? extends VCard> collection) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends VCard> collection) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void clear() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean contains(Object object) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> collection) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public VCard get(int location) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public int indexOf(Object object) {
                            return 0;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean isEmpty() {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public Iterator<VCard> iterator() {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public int lastIndexOf(Object object) {
                            return 0;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public ListIterator<VCard> listIterator() {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public ListIterator<VCard> listIterator(int location) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public VCard remove(int location) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean remove(Object object) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> collection) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> collection) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public VCard set(int location, VCard object) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public int size() {
                            return 0;
                        }

                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public List<VCard> subList(int start, int end) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public Object[] toArray() {
                            return new Object[0];
                        }

                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public <T> T[] toArray(T[] array) {
                            return null;
                        }
                    } ;
```

and when I try to add vcards to it, I get a NullPointerException. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
List<VCard> vcards = new ArrayList<VCard>();
```

Hope it helps.